# Update value of a variable from a function in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

```
a=master
b="9876"

secondfunction(){
    a=develop
    b="1234"
    echo "Inside second function"
    echo $1
    echo $2
}

secondfunction $a $b
```

In the above shell script echo command prints a=master and b=9876. I want to print a=develop and b =1234.

Comment: `I want to print a=develop and b =1234.` Then print `$a` and `$b`

Comment: You pass `$a` (which contains at this point _master_) to `secondfunction`. In it, $1 is therefore _master_. Further down, you do a `echo $1`, so ofcourse it prints _master_.

Comment: `$1` and `$2` are not references to variables; they are parameters *initialized* using the value of the variables. Changing `a` after `secondfunction` has been called doesn't change the fact that `$1` was initialized using the original value of `a`.

Comment: `secondfunction $a $b` is exactly equivalent to `secondfunction master 9876` after parameter expansion: there is no link to the expanded parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are indeed changing the value of `a` and `b` like you want to, To see this you can print out `a` and `b` after the function has been called

```sh
echo $a $b
secondfunction $a $b
echo $a $b
```

and you can see that the output will be `master 9876` for the first one and `develop 1234` for the second one. Just that you cannot change the value of `$1` and `$2` by changing the values of `a` and `b`. For that you'll need to explicitly change them using `set` like @william has pointed out.

Also variables in shell script are globally scoped unless explicitly mentioned otherwise. So if all you want to do is change the values of those variables, you need not explicitly pass them into the function as arguments.

```sh
a=master
b="9876"

secondfunction(){
    a=develop
    b="1234"
    echo "Inside second function"
    echo $a
    echo $b
}

secondfunction
```

will also work

Comment: `$1` and `$2` can be changed.  `secondfunction() { set develop 1234; a=$1; b=$1; echo "$1"; echo "$2"; }`

Comment: Oh yeah yes. I guess you can change the positional parameters first and then set the variables to the positional parameters. I didn't think of that. I was just trying to point out how they couldn't directly change the value of the parameters like they assumed. I should probably improve the phrasing of my answer